# Recursive computation of determinant of Toeplitz tridiagonal matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant, numerical-linear-algebra, tridiagonal-matrices, toeplitz-matrices

> Let a matrix be a tridiagonal matrix of size $n \times n$, with elements equal to $2$ on the main diagonal, elements equal to $1$ directly above the main diagonal, elements equal to $3$ directly below the main diagonal, and with zeros in all other elements:
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 2 & 1 &   &   &  &  \\
> 3 & 2 & 1 &   &  &  \\
>   & 3 & 2 & 1 &  &  \\
>   &   & 3 & 2 & \ddots  &  \\
>   &   &   & \ddots & \ddots & 1\\
>   &   &   &   & 3 & 2
> \end{bmatrix}
> Express the determinant $A (n)$ using the determinants $A (n-2)$ and $A (n-1)$.

---

Could you explain me how this task is supposed to be done?

Comment: **Hint.** Use Laplace expansion with respect to the first row. There are two terms: one is immediately seen to be $2 \cdot \det(A(n-1))$, the other will involve $\det(A(n-2))$ with a coefficient.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: @AndreasCaranti I was going to post this as an answer to que question. You did indeed answer it.

Comment: @OlivierRoche could you post as answer?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1386260/339790)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Laplace expansion with respect to the first row we have

$$\begin{aligned}
A_{n} &= \det\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 
3 & 2 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\ 
0 & 3 & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 
\vdots& \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & \cdots & 3 & 2
\end{bmatrix} \\
&=2A_{n-1} - \det\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 & \cdots & 0 \\ 
\vdots& \vdots & \ddots &\vdots  \\ 
0 & 0 & \cdots & 2
\end{bmatrix} \\
&=2A_{n-1}-3A_{n-2}.\\
\end{aligned}$$

Answer (score 0):

<sub>The following is more of a long comment than an answer per se.</sub>

---

Using [SymPy](http://sympy.org):

```
from sympy import *


def f(i,j):
    if   i - j ==  1:   
        return 3
    elif i - j ==  0:
        return 2
    elif i - j == -1:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0


def T(n):
    return Matrix(n, n, lambda i,j: f(i,j)) 


print([ T(n).det() for n in range(1,11) ])
```

which outputs

```
[2, 1, -4, -11, -10, 13, 56, 73, -22, -263]
```

which, according to OEIS, are the **generalized Gaussian Fibonacci integers** ([A088137](https://oeis.org/A088137)).

---

[oeis](/questions/tagged/oeis)

Comment: Who wants to submit this information to OEIS?