# Is there a good lower bound for $|\sin(k\theta)|$ when $e^{i\theta}$ is algebraic and $\theta/\pi$ is irrational?

Tags: number-theory

The precise question is: given $\lambda>1$, does there always exist $C>0$ such that $|\sin(k\theta)|>C\lambda^{-k}$ for all $k$?

My original purpose is to show that: whenever $\lambda>1$, and $\theta$ is given as in the title, one has
$\lim_{k\to\infty}\lambda^k|\sin(k\theta)|=+\infty$.

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: achille hui's answer to this posting will help. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705877/an-exotic-sequence?noredirect=1&lq=1